# Scraping: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL with cURL. Works in Chrome/Firefox

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, ssl, curl, web-scraping

## Motivation

I'm currently an exchange student at Taiwan Tech in Taipei, but the course overview/search engine is not very comfortable to use - so I'm trying to scrape it, which unexpectedly leads to a lot of difficulties.

## Problem

Opening `https://qcourse.ntust.edu.tw` works just fine when using Chrome/Firefox, however, I run in to trouble when trying to use command line interfaces:

```sh
# Trying to use curl:
$ curl https://qcourse.ntust.edu.tw
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to qcourse.ntust.edu.tw:443

# Trying to use wget:
$ wget https://qcourse.ntust.edu.tw
--2019-02-25 12:13:55--  https://qcourse.ntust.edu.tw/
Loaded CA certificate '/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'
Resolving qcourse.ntust.edu.tw (qcourse.ntust.edu.tw)... 140.118.242.168
Connecting to qcourse.ntust.edu.tw (qcourse.ntust.edu.tw)|140.118.242.168|:443... connected.
GnuTLS: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

[I also run into trouble when trying to use the browser Pale Moon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2dke.png)

## What I've considered

#### Maybe there is a problem with the certificate itself?

Seemingly not:

```sh
# This uses the same wildcard certificate (*.ntust.edu.tw) as qcourse.ntust.edu.tw
# (I double checked, and the SHA256 fingerprint is identical)
$ curl https://www.ntust.edu.tw
<html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=bin/home.php'><title>title</title></head></html>%
```

#### Maybe I need specific headers that only Chrome/Firefox sends by default?

It seems like this doesn't solve anything either. By opening the request (Network tab) in Chrome, right clicking, and choosing "Copy" > "Copy as cURL", I get the same error message as earlier.

#### Additional information

The course overview site is written in ASP.NET, and seems to be running on Microsoft IIS httpd 6.0.

---

I find this quite mysterious and intriguing. I hope someone might be able to offer an explanation of this behaviour, and if possible: a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the [SSLLabs report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=qcourse.ntust.edu.tw) this is a server with a terrible setup. It is getting a rating of F since it supports the totally broken SSLv2, mostly broken SSLv3 and many many totally broken ciphers. The only kind of secure way to access this server is using TLS 1.0 with `TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA` (3DES), a cipher which is not considered insecure as the others but only weak.

Only, since 3DES is considered weak (albeit not insecure) it is disabled by default in most modern TLS stacks. One need to specifically enable the support for it. For curl with OpenSSL backend this would look like this, provided that the OpenSSL library you use still supports 3DES in the first place (not the case with default build of OpenSSL 1.1.1):

```
$ curl -v --cipher '3DES' https://qcourse.ntust.edu.tw
```

Comment: This would explain why it was working for `www.ntust.edu.tw`, since this site is a bit more updated - and supports TLS/more secure cipher suits. I guess the course overview site was made ages ago, and the person who made it is long gone from the workplace.

Comment: I actually still get the same error, even when running `$ curl -v --cipher '3DES' https://qcourse.ntust.edu.tw`. EDIT: Seems like cURL is trying to use TLSv1.3

Comment: @TobiasBergkvist: it might be that your curl is not linked against openssl but against some other TLS library like NSS. In this case the syntax for specifying the cipher is different. For NSS it would be `rsa_3des_sha` according to https://curl.haxx.se/docs/ssl-ciphers.html. Use `curl --version` to find out which backend your curl is using.

Comment: curl 7.64.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.64.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1a zlib/1.2.11 libidn2/2.1.1 libpsl/0.20.2 (+libidn2/2.1.1) libssh2/1.8.0 nghttp2/1.36.0 Release-Date: 2019-02-06 --- In other words, quite bleeding edge, and my OpenSSL seems to be built without SSLv2/3 support.

Comment: @TobiasBergkvist: OpenSSL 1.1.1 is bleading edge. Missing SSLv2/v3 support is not the problem as long TLS 1.0 is there. But the default build has disabled 3DES too. This means, there is no chance to access this broken site with the modern TLS stack you use.

Comment: I suppose my best shot is using Docker then. Thanks for the help!